# Very Basic Example - Enable or Disable a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-forms

I have this very basic example. This should work in a form for multiple inputs as well.

I want a form without any required parameters. But I only want to enable the button if at least one of them is not empty.

`$pristine` almost works. **The problem is that if I type something and delete it the button remains enabled.**

Basically,

If all fields are empty -> button disabled

Else if at least one not empty -> button enabled

```js
function ctrl($scope){
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name='myName' ng-model='myName'/>
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine" />
    {{myForm.$pristine}}
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pristine checks whether the input field is touched or not. That's why it remains enabled after you deleted your input. Check on valid and provide some condition. Or use pattern and regex.

Comment: why not comment? this is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `disabled="!name.length"` instead of `ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine"`.

This will solve your issue. Below is working code:

```js
function ctrl($scope) {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name='myName' ng-model='myName' />
    
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="!name.length" />
    
 {{myForm.myName.$pristine}}
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Comment: remove ng-required = true **I want a form without any required parameters**

Comment: @user10111311 please check my answer. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

## With `required`:

```js
    function ctrl($scope) {
       
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" name='myName' ng-model='myName' required/>
        <span>{{name}}</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

## Without required using controller:

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.isDisable = true;
    $scope.validate = function(){
      if($scope.name == undefined || $scope.name == ""){
            $scope.isDisable = true;
      } else {
            $scope.isDisable = false;
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name='myName' ng-model='myName' ng-keyup = "validate()"/>
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  ng-disabled="isDisable"/>
</form>
</div>
```

## Another way using `name.length`:

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
           
}
```

```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

        <div ng-app>
        <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" name='myName'/>
            <span>{{name}}</span>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"  ng-disabled="!name.length"/>{{name.length}}
        </form>
        </div>
```

**Note:** If you don't want to use HTML5 validation that you can mark your form `novalidate`.

Comment: Then you have to control from a controller.

Comment: @user10111311 edited answer without required parameters.

Comment: @user10111311 added the last snippet using `name.length`. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is naive way, but you can just use ng-model of each input in ng-disabled

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name='myName' />
    <input type="text" ng-model="fName" name='FirstName'/>
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  ng-disabled="!(name || fName)" />
    {{myForm.$pristine}}
</form>
</div>
```

Also, your code has 2 ng-model for the same input